# Complete vector field and metric

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a manifold, and $X$ a (smooth) vector field on $M$. If there is a metric $\rho$ on $M$ such that $\rho(M)$ is bounded, then $X$ is complete (no blow-up in finite time). But I don't see how the property of completeness depends on a metric. So what happens if we replace the metric $\rho$ with another non-equivalent metric inducing the same topology, but for which $X$ is not bounded ? Is it still complete ?

The example I have in mind : $M$ is a hyperbolic open set in the complex plane, $X$ is a $C^1$ vector field. You can either choose the hyperbolic or euclidean metric.

Comment: Do you have a source for your claim?  I would double check the hypotheses :-)

Answer (score 0):

As stated, this is false: take the interval $(-1,1)$ with Euclidean metric, and the vector field $\frac{d}{dx}$.

A wild guess: $M$ is also assumed to be complete. Then the claim is true, because a complete and bounded manifold (without boundary) must be a [closed manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_manifold). On a closed manifold, every smooth field can flow forever.